# DC/DC synchronous buck converter LM5117

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I'm trying to simulate the typical circuit for the LM5117 in PSpice for TI. The simulation does not run properly and it gave an error because of the "transistors and diodes I was using". Therefore, I used ideal switches and put the RON = 10m

[image]

but the simulation error persists. I am still trying to figure out what is wrong. The circuit typical circuit which I'm trying to simulate is the following one:

[image]

Image source: [Texas Instruments - LM5117 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snvs698f/snvs698f.pdf?ts=1705434814152&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

and this is the error that shows...

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For clarification, I am trying to simulate the typical circuit for a LM5117 dc-dc synchronous buck converter shown on the second image which can be found on the LM5117 datasheet, page 22. [link] (chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snvs698f/snvs698f.pdf?ts=1705434814152&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

Comment: The first image is a screenshot of the typical LM5117 circuit which I built in PSpice for TI.

Comment: I used a couple of imported models for the transistors that were needed to complete the typical circuit but I got the error shown on the third image. Afterwards, I used ideal switches with a RON of 10m ohms instead of those transistors to see if the error will go away but it keeps appearing anyway.